# Undefined property: stdClass::$id when retriving term ID

Tags: categories

I have the following:

```
foreach( $this_post_terms as $term ) :
  $thiscat = get_term_by( 'slug', $term->slug, 'categories_whatever' );
  echo $thiscat->ID;
endforeach;
```

The last line throws an error, Undefined property: stdClass::$ID.

What's weird to me is that

```
echo $thiscat->name;
```

works, doesn't throw any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields returned by `get_term_by()` are:

- term_id
- name
- slug
- term_group
- term_taxonomy_id
- taxonomy
- description
- parent
- count

So instead of `$thiscat->ID`, you should use `$thiscat->term_id`

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

Answer (score 1):

Not weird, there is no `ID` in a term object, it's `term_id`. You can also `var_dump($thiscat)` in your loop to see all of its properties.

Comment: You beat me to it :)